# A context for a top level index-only key in JSON-LD

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, json-ld, linked-data

I am trying to use JSON-LD to make a legacy JSON file machine readable. The JSON file in question has a top-level object with an `item` member referencing an object that contains the actual relevant data.

```
{
  "item": {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Test"
  }
}
```

When I now introduce a context like the following:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": "https://example.org/name"
  }
}
```

No knowledge is extracted meaning no triples can be interpreted from this. To make it work, I realized I could do the following:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "item": "https://example.org/exists",
    "name": "https://example.org/name"
  }
}
```

This one works, meaning a triple with the name predicate is extracted nicely. The problem with this approach however is, that an unnecessary triple with the `exists` predicate is also extracted.

Therefore I experimented with marking the top-level object as an index container, so that the `item` key is completely ignored. I just don't find a way to do this without the need to assign an IRI to the `item` term and if I assign one, again the unnecessary triple is extracted again.

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": "https://example.org/name"
  }
}
```

No knowledge is extracted meaning no triples can be interpreted from this. To make it work, I realized I could do the following:

This doesn't work at all (because the `item` term has no IRI):

```
{
  "@context": {
    "item": {
      "@container": "@index"
    },
    "name": "https://example.org/name"
  }
}
```

And this does work but has the unnecessary triples again:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@container": "@index",
    "item": "https://example.org/exists",
    "name": "https://example.org/name"
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? How can I create a context that only extracts the `name` triple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this against your JSON-LD processor:

```json
{
  "item": {
    "id":   "123",
    "name": "Test"
  } ,
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/id/",
    "id":    "@id", 
    "item":  "@nest",
    "name":  "https://example.org/name"
  } 
}
```

In JSON-LD Playground, this context [produces](https://json-ld.org/playground/?startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22item%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22123%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Test%22%7D%2C%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fid%2F%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22item%22%3A%22%40nest%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fname%22%7D%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%22item%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fexists%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fname%22%7D) the following single RDF triple:

```
<http://example.com/id/123> <https://example.org/name> "Test" .
```

JSON-LD features used:

- [4.1.6 Keyword Aliasing](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#aliasing-keywords) (`"id": "@id"`);
- [4.4 Nested Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#nested-properties) (`"item": "@nest"`) — [new](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#nested-properties) in JSON-LD 1.1.

You could also be interested in [RML](https://rml.io/specs/rml/).

Comment: That does it. Thank you so much.